# Using lodash _.memoize combine with _.random

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash, memoization

I saw this code written by someone (in angularjs), and I want to know how this work (just ask for my knowledge):

```
    $scope.changeVisibility = function() {
        $scope.visibility = _.memoize(function() {
            return !!_.random(0, 4);
        });
    };
    $scope.changeVisibility()
```

and extra HTML for view (changeVisibility and visibility are used):

```
<button ng-click="changeVisibility()">Visibility change</button>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col" visible="visibility(1)">
    1. Row, 1. Col
  </div>

  <div class="col" visible="visibility(2)">
    Mark Hane<br>
    28 yearold<br>
    234 SG
  </div>

  <div class="col" visible="visibility(3)">
    <div class="row"  ng-if="visibility(3)">
      1. Row, 3. Col, 1. Row --  1<br>
      1. Row, 3. Col, 1. Row --  2
    </div>
    <div class="row"  ng-if="visibility(3)">
      1. Row, 3. Col, 2. Row --  1<br>
      1. Row, 3. Col, 2. Row --  2<br>
      1. Row, 3. Col, 2. Row --  3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
... so on to  visibility(9)
</div>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What part of the code do you not understand? What is happening when you run the code, what matches your expectations? Did you try calling the memoized function in the console to explore how it behaves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it **hides** some of the content if it rolled a **0** in the `visibility` function. Basically, it has a small chance of 1/X to be hidden, where X is the highest range in `_.random(0,X)`. It stores this generated number in **cache** for a particular index with `_.memoize` (possibly to reduce $digest cycle executables for each watcher).

Here is a similar code to see how it works ([Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PeioSw96UA2fAoyTRbVY?p=preview)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="changeVisibility()">Visibility change</button>
    <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
      visibility({{$index+1}}) - {{visibility($index+1)}}
      <span ng-if="visibility($index+1)">- [i c u]</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.changeVisibility = function() {
        $scope.visibility = _.memoize(function() {
          return !!_.random(0, 10);
        });
      };
      $scope.changeVisibility(); // initialise 
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: and memoize return a function accept a argument, right? I don't see the input function of memoize has argument, can you explain for me?

Comment: @phongly it [returns the new memoizing function](https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2#memoize). if you display `{{visibility}}` without parameters you will see it's a function that has JS [**arguments**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments): `function (){var e=arguments,u=t?t.apply(this,e):e[0],i=r.cache;if(i.has(u))return i.get(u);var o=n.apply(this,e);return r.cache=i.set(u,o)||i,o}`